# Sample code for Unicode XML parsing using PugiXML

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, unicode

I have tried to find some code for this job in the tutorials and by googling, no luck.

If someone has used PugiXml, could you please help me out ?

My main trouble is Unicode, otherwise the library is very easy to use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see that PugiXML currently assumes that all input is UTF-8.  Are you having trouble parsing a UTF-8 file or are you trying to use PugiXML with wchar_t/wstring or ...?

Comment: Actually I am trying to use a wchar_t[] array to store data.

Comment: Looks like the key is to use `pugi::as_utf8()` to pass wchar_t data to PugiXML and `pugi::as_utf16()` to get wchar_t data out.  I assume that all char* strings used by PugiXML are UTF-8, but it's not clear from the documentation.

Comment: Just a side note: are you sure that a title starting with "Give me ..." is the best way to introduce a question?   
I find it rather irratating, but it could just be me

Comment: Might want to try asking questions rather giving commands. We don't work for you.

Comment: @Wartin: I do not know PugiXML but i'm now facing a problem regarding xml parsing in c++... I chose to use RapidXML and then Xerces... I would recommend you (for small app) RapidXML.

Comment: @Andry: RapidXML doesn't (necessarily) do what he wants either. To get it to parse to UTF-16, you have to provide the file data in UTF-16 format. So he'd have to check the file to see if it's UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

Open pugiconfig.hpp and uncomment PUGIXML_WCHAR_MODE.

Now you can use wchar_t and std::wstring instead of char and std::string respectively.

Quick Start is here: http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/quickstart.html

Comment: What does this have to do with Unicode? UTF-8 is a perfectly valid Unicode encoding.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas It depends on the platform. On windows you cannot fit a unicode character into type char. It must be wchar_t. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring

Comment: First, Unicode does not have characters; it has code points, code units, and graphemes. Second, UTF-8 **is a perfectly valid Unicode encoding**; what platform you're working on is *irrelevant* to that fact. UTF-8 doesn't stop working just because you're on Windows. Yes, to open a file who's name isn't using ASCII characters, you need to convert it to UTF-16 on Windows. But that's a matter of the API interface, not of the nature of "Unicode". Microsoft does not dictate what "Unicode" means.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas You cannot parse unicode using PUGI on Windows without PUGIXML_WCHAR_MODE. If you try the result will be garbage.

Comment: No, you cannot parse into UTF-16 without that. You will normally get UTF-8, which is *not garbage*.