# Read UNICODE chars from .txt file and output them to console

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, unicode

I have very simple question, but my 4 hours of searching for answer did not help me.
I have a text file in which i wrote: **šđčćžŠĐČĆŽ**

I do not know how to read this properly and output it in console.
Please help me. I am using C++ Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your console definitely *support* those characters? What encoding is the file in?

Comment: Can you post some of the code you've tried?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes my console supports those characters. I have been working with them, but not from files. DanPichelman I currently do not have any code, I am pissed off and nervous... so I deleted everything that I got and started all over again with this question.

Comment: You are using a text file whose encoding we don't know.  You are using a language whose standard largely ignores Unicode.  You are using a way to display the text that stopped making sense 20 years ago.  It is pretty unclear where you want to start tackling this problem.

Comment: If this is ANSI then assuming you are on windows (visual-studio-2010 tag) you should use MultiByteToWideChar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How has it been encoded? If it is UTF-16, use [`std::wifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)! If other encoding is needed.

If it is UTF-8: [use codec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775437/read-unicode-file-into-wstring).