# C++ / wcout / UTF-8

Tags: c++, windows, encoding, utf-8

I'm reading a UTF-8 encoded unicode text file, and outputting it into the console, but the displayed characters are not the same as in the text editor i used to create the file. Here is my code :

```
#define UNICODE

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include "pugixml.hpp"

using std::ifstream;
using std::ios;
using std::string;
using std::wstring;

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    ifstream oFile;

    try
    {
        string sContent;

        oFile.open ( "../config-sample.xml", ios::in );

        if( oFile.is_open() )
        {
            wchar_t wsBuffer[128];

            while( oFile.good() )
            {
                oFile >> sContent;
                mbstowcs( wsBuffer, sContent.c_str(), sizeof( wsBuffer ) );
              //wprintf( wsBuffer );// Same result as wcout.
                wcout << wsBuffer;
            }

            Sleep(100000);
        }
        else
        {
            throw L"Failed to open file";
        }
    }
    catch( const wchar_t * pwsMsg )
    {
        ::MessageBox( NULL, pwsMsg, L"Error", MB_OK | MB_TOPMOST | MB_SETFOREGROUND );
    }

    if( oFile.is_open() )
    {
        oFile.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There must be something i don't get about encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a `mbstowcs` doesn't actually use UTF-8. It uses an older style of "multibyte codepoints", which is not compatible with UTF-8 (although technically is is possible [I believe] to define a UTF-8 codepage, there is no such thing in Windows).

If you want to convert UTF-8 to UTF-16, you can use [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), with a `codepage` of `CP_UTF8`.

Answer (score 3):

Wide strings don't mean UTF-8. In fact, it's quite the opposite: UTF-8 means Unicode Transformation Format (8 bits); it's a way to represent Unicode over 8-bit characters, so your normal `char`s. You should read it into normal strings (not wide strings).

Wide strings use `wchar_t`, which on Windows is 16 bits. The OS uses UTF-16 for its "wide" functions.

On Windows, UTF-8 strings can be converted to UTF-16 using [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: So i need to convert my UTF-8 text to UTF-16 so windows can use it ?

Comment: Most functions that accept strings can be suffixed with either A or W to indicate if the string is a char string or a wchar_t string. If your API only has a wide string variant, yes, you need to convert. Otherwise, it depends on if the functions accept UTF-8 or not (I'm not sure about that). If it doesn't, you'll still need to convert, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I made a C++ `char_t` container that hold up to 6 8-bit char_t storing it in a `std::vector`. Converting it to and from `wchar_t` or appending it to a `std::string`.

Check it out here:
[View UTF-8_String structures on Github](https://github.com/iBeanSoftware/iBS_LIB/blob/master/UTF-8_String.h)

```
#include "UTF-8_String.h" //header from github link above

iBS::u8str  raw_v;
iBS::readu8file("TestUTF-8File.txt",raw_v);
std::cout<<raw_v.str()<<std::endl;
```

Here is functions that converts wchar_t to a uint32_t in the u8char struct fond in header above.

```
    #include <cwchar>

    u8char& operator=(wchar_t& wc)
    {
        char temp[6];
        std::mbstate_t state ;
        int ret = std::wcrtomb((&temp[0]), wc, &state);
        ref.resize(ret);
        for (short i=0; i<ret; ++i) 
            ref[i]=temp[i];
        return *this;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I find `wifstream` works very good, even in visual studio debugger shows UTF-8 words correctly (I'm reading traditional chinese words), from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775437/read-unicode-utf-8-file-into-wstring):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>

std::wstring readFile(const char* filename)
{
    std::wifstream wif(filename);
    wif.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << wif.rdbuf();
    return wss.str();
}
 
//  usage
std::wstring wstr2;
wstr2 = readFile("C:\\yourUtf8File.txt");
wcout << wstr2;
```