# use wstring get line read file

Tags: c++, string, ifstream, wstring

I have a file that contains text, I would like to get each line from this file into a `std::wstring` variable.If I do this I get an error, so is it possible to use `std::wstring` or I'm obligate to use a `std::string` ? This is my code :

```
std::ifstream fichier( "text.txt" );

if ( fichier )
{
  std::wstring ligne;

  while ( std::getline( fichier, ligne ) )
  {
      //work with ligne
  }
}
```

As mentioned, if I replace `std::wstring` by `std::string` I have no errors.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try to use `std::wifstream` instead of `std::ifstream`

Answer (score 0):

To use wstring read file, I find `wifstream` works very good, even in visual studio debugger shows UTF-8 words correctly (I'm reading traditional chinese), from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775437/read-unicode-utf-8-file-into-wstring):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>

std::wstring readFile(const char* filename)
{
    std::wifstream wif(filename);
    wif.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << wif.rdbuf();
    return wss.str();
}

//  usage
std::wstring wstr2;
wstr2 = readFile("C:\\yourUtf8File.txt");
wcout << wstr2;
```