# C++11: is std::locale::empty() even a thing?

Tags: c++, c++11, locale

Trying to compile [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10607146/5112564) from StackOverflow, basically, these lines:

```
std::wifstream wif(filename);
wif.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));
```

GCC version: `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0`

I get a compile error:

> 'empty' is not a member of 'std::locale'

And I agree with the compiler, checked with documentation like [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) - there is no info about such thing. Header files as well do not show anything.

I wonder, if this is just me or the sample code from another topic...

Can it be a MSVC feature? (the sample code I used is from the question related to Windows)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1w3527e2(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a platform-specific extension to the locale class, and it used to be described in [this MSVC documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/1w3527e2(v=VS.71).aspx)*:

> In this implementation, you can also call the static member function:
>
> ```
> static locale empty( );
> ```
>
> to construct a `locale` object that has no facets. It is also a transparent locale; if the template functions `has_facet` and `use_facet` cannot find the requested facet in a transparent locale, they consult first the global locale and then, if that is transparent, the classic locale.

* the MSVC documentation link is outdated now, for best replacement see [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/locale-class?view=vs-2019) instead

Comment: I guess the phrase *"In this implementation"* is key - it's a platform-specific extension rather that a standard member.

Comment: @TobySpeight indeed, it is an extension provided by MSVC (I guess, in reality, it is only applicable to some of the versions)

Comment: like has been dead. Updated version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/locale-class?view=vs-2019

Comment: @phuclv I guess you mean __the link__, thanks, will update

Answer (score 0):

Using std::locale() instead of std::locale:empty() worked for me.