# What is the correct way to read a file content to wchar_t (4Bytes) on macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, file

As we know `wchar_t` is 2Bytes on windows but 4bytes on macOS/Linux.

I am trying to read a file that has a Unicode string but that string has read incorrectly (unknown symbols).

```
basic_ifstream<wchar_t> file("/Documents/file.txt", ios_base::ate); // or wifstream
if(!file.is_open()){
    cout << "Cannot open the file." << endl;
}
streamsize size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0);
wstring str (size, 0); // or (size / 4, 0)
file.read(reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(&str[0]) , size);
file.close();
```

When debugging that code to see whether the string has read correctly, I found the string is being read incorrectly (unknown symbols).

**What is the correct way to read a Unicode file content into `wchar_t`?**

Answer (score 0):

One way to read correctly is:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream> // for wifstream
    #include <codecvt> // for locale & codecvt_utf8
    #include <sstream> // for wstringstream
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        wifstream wif("file.txt");
        wif.imbue(locale(locale::empty(), new codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>));
        wstringstream wss;
        wss << wif.rdbuf();
        wstring wstr = wss.str();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `No member named 'empty' in 'std::__1::locale'` , I have changed `empty()` to `locale()`, and still it's not working.

Comment: It should work. Have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41781945/13292734 - here is explanation about your problem.

Comment: It works on windows but mac OS, unfortunately, does not until now.

Comment: try with codecvt_utf8_utf16 instead of codecvt_utf8.

Comment: Still the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way is using a one line Cocoa function that reads the contents of a file as an NSString, taking care of character encoding.

Comment: So, how to put the file content back to C++?