# Unable to read UTF-8 (Hebrew text) from a file in C++

Tags: c++, string, file, utf-8, wstring

I have a txt file (encoded in UTF-8) that contains the following text:

```
שלום עולם!
```

I tried to read the text and print it on the screen like this:

```cpp
std::wifstream file("file.txt");
std::wstring line;
while (std::getline(file, line)) {
    std::wcout << line << std::endl;
}
file.close();
```

But the output I get is:

```
╫⌐╫£╫ץ╫¥ ╫ó╫ץ╫£╫¥!
```

I tried:

- Using `ifstream`, `string`, `cout` instead of `wifstream`, `wstring`, `wcout`.
- Printing const hebrew string to the screen, resulting in me seeing the string properly:

```cpp
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), 0x00040000);
std::wcout << L"שלום עולם!" << std::endl;
```

Resulting in:

```
שלום עולם!
```

Comment: How is the output device configured? For `UTF-8`? Or something else?

Comment: Some relevant info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775437/read-unicode-utf-8-file-into-wstring