# Reading from file with special characters into a string

Tags: c++, fstream

I have an c++ program that should read a text from a file named "Pontaje.txt" and store it into a string. The problem is that in that file is an special character and the program can't use it properly.

Pontaje.txt

```
[604] Dumy | 17501 — Today at 12:01 AM
```

Note that "—"(is a special character) is not "-"(from the keyboard)

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream test("Pontaje.txt");
    std::string test2;
    std::getline(test, test2);
    std::cout << test2;
}
```

Output:

```
∩╗┐[604] Dumy | 17501 ΓÇö Today at 12:01 AM
```

How can I assign in test2 that line properly?

Note that I've tried using `std::wifstream` , `std::wstring` and `std::wcout` but i get the same result

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775437/read-unicode-utf-8-file-into-wstring

Comment: What happens if you just run: `std::cout << "[604] Dumy | 17501 — Today at 12:01 AM"`? Does it print correctly then? If not, then it is likely to be a problem with your console (what happens if you paste the line there?) or it might be that you are using a old compiler.

Comment: Almost,  ``` [604] Dumy | 17501 ù Today at 12:01 AM ```
I don t think the compiler is the problem because I use Visual Studio with the latest updates

Comment: Have you tried executing it from `Tools > Command Line > Developer Command Prompt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ΓÇö` is a tell-tale sign: it's three characters instead of one. That happens when the input is encoded using UTF-8 (a multi-byte character set) but the output is done with a single-byte character set. I can't directly eyeball what character set contains all of `ΓÇö`, though.

IOW the problem is not the input or the output, but the assumption that they're using the same character set. And `std::string` makes no assumptions at all about character sets.