# Accessing individual characters (wchar_t) in a wstring

Tags: c++, iteration, wchar-t, wstring

I am reading in text from a file that contains unicode characters and I store the text into a `wstring`. I am interested in iterating over the `wstring` to determine which characters need more than one byte for storage.

My issue is that `str.length()` (*where `str` is a `wstring`*) seems to be indicating the number of bytes in the string instead of the number of characters. Also, as I iterate over the string using `str[i]`, the bracket operator seems to return only 1 byte.

**Here is some example code to replicate my issue:**

```
wifstream inFile;
inFile.open(L"myFile.txt");
    
wstring str;
getline(inFile, str);

wcout << str.length() << endl;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
  wcout << str[i] << L" (" << (unsigned int)str[i] << L')' << endl;
}

wofstream outFile;  outFile.open(L"outFile.txt");
outFile << str << endl;

outFile.close();
inFile.close();
```

**Output of code:**

```
5
H (72)
├ (195)
í (161)
l (108)
o (111)
```

I tried with a file that contains the string `"Hálo"`. `str.length()` reports 5, which appears to be minimum number of bytes needed to store the string (*assuming you use one byte for all characters except for the á*). This confuses me because `sizeof(wchar_t)` is 2 within my environment. I figure an array of 4 characters within the wstring would require 8 bytes minimum. Yet, it seems `"Hálo"` is being stored as `01001000 {11000011 10100001} 01101100 01101100` (*curly brackets to indicate the unicode character*). So as I iterate over this, I get everything returned as if they were just `char` and that unicode character `á` comes back as 2 characters `├í`.

Strangely enough, when I write the wstring to a file (*seen in the code above*), the text comes out as expected with the unicode character properly interpreted.

Is there a way to iterate over the actual characters within the `wstring` instead of just the bytes? Also, why is the `wstring` storing it in just 5 bytes instead of 8? I suppose it saves space but it makes accessing the elements seem unintuitive.

**EDIT:** I understand that my terminal may not be able to display a `wchar_t` properly, though I would still hope to print the integer value of it.

Comment: Is your file utf-8 encoded? If you're on Windows see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775437/read-unicode-utf-8-file-into-wstring

Comment: Unicode is more than one thing. It is a family of encodings. First you need to know what unicode encoding is being used by the file. Do you have that information?

Comment: `11000011 10100001` is indeed the UTF-8 encoding of code point U+00E1 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE.  You will need to do a conversion if you want the data represented as UTF-16 or UTF-32.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I think the correct answer here is the first sentence of your comment, plus all of Remy's.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you. I imbued the wifstream with "en_US.UTF8" and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

All that you said about `std::wstring` is incorrect. It does not store *bytes*, and its `length()` is not expressed in *bytes* (those are true for `std::string` instead).

`std::wstring` holds `wchar_t` chars, and its `length()` is the number of `wchar_t` elements in the string.  On Windows `wchar_t` is 2 bytes (used for UCS-2/UTF-16), whereas on other platforms `wchar_t` is 4 bytes (used for UTF-32).

To read a file into a `std::wstring` using `std::wifstream`, you need to `imbue()` the correct `std::locale` into the `std::wifstream` to handle the file's encoding (ANSI, UTF-8, etc) so it can be decoded into `wchar_t` characters.

In your case, your file is encoded in UTF-8, as the UTF-8 encoded form of `Hálo` is the byte sequence:

```
H - 0x48
á - 0xC3 0xA1
l - 0x6C
o - 0x6F
```

Since your `std::wifstream` doesn't know the data is UTF-8, it is simply upscaling each byte as-is into a `wchar_t`.  You need to `imbue()` a UTF-8 locale into the stream to read this file, so that the bytes `0xC3 0xA1` are correctly interpreted as `á` rather than `├í`.

Comment: It is not required that `sizeof(wchar_t) > sizeof(char)`.  If `CHAR_BIT` is at least 16, then `sizeof (wchar_t)` is allowed to be 1.  (Such platforms are usually not considered good choices for string processing, so it's unlikely to be seen in practice.  But allowed)