# Cannot read to file(exist) with UNICODE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unicode, utf-8, fread

I have a project which need to read path of SysData file.I want to move SysData file which contains "ç","ş","ğ" path way but cannot read this char.I have to read with UNICODE(like that utf-8).

There is code;

```
bool TSimTextFileStream::ReadLine  ( mstring * str )
{
        *str = "";
        char c = ' ';
        bool first = true;
        // while ( read ( hFile, &c, 1 ) )
        while ( fread ( &c, 1, 1, hFile ) )
        {
                if (first) first = false;
                #ifdef __linux__
                        if ( c == 13 )
                                continue;
                                else
                        if ( c == 10 )
                                break;
                                else
                                *str += c;
                #else
                         if( c == 13 || c == 10)
                             break;
                         else
                             *str += c;

                #endif
        }
        return !first;
}
```

And there is code, calling this method;

```
mstring GetSysDataDirectory ( )
{
    static mstring sysDataDir = "";
    if ( sysDataDir == "" )
    {
    if (mIsEnvironmentVarExist("SYSDATAPATH"))
    {
      mstring folder = mGetEnvVar("SYSDATAPATH");

      if (folder.size() == 0)
      {
        folder = mGetCurrentDir ( ) + "/SysData";
      }

      sysDataDir = folder;
    }
        else if ( mIsFileExist ( "SysDataPath.dat" ) )
        {
            TSimTextFileStream txtfile;
            txtfile.OpenFileForRead( "SysDataPath.dat" );
            mstring folder;
            if ( txtfile.ReadLine( &folder ) )
            {
                sysDataDir = folder;
            }
            else
            {
                sysDataDir = mGetCurrentDir ( ) + "/SysData";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sysDataDir = mGetCurrentDir ( ) + "/SysData";
        }
    }

    return sysDataDir;
}
```

I search and find some solution but not work, like that;

```
bool TSimTextFileStream::OpenFileForRead(mstring fname)
{
        if (hFile != NULL) CloseFile();

        hFile = fopen(fname.c_str(), "r,ccs=UNICODE");

        if (hFile == NULL) return false; else return true;
}
```

and tried this;

```
hFile = fopen(fname.c_str(), "r,ccs=UTF-8");
```

But not work again. Can you help me please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXP2C.png)

This situation is my problem :((

Comment: You didn't explain what the problem is, apart from the custom file-reading code. Visual C++ supports Unicode for at least 20 years. Most applications on Windows use Unicode for almost that long. You *don't* need to write your own code to read text files. UTF8 can be read/written just like *any* string though, it doesn't even need the Unicode-specific (ie UTF16/32) functions. What is `mstring`, why don't you use `std::string` and streams ?

Comment: Have you tried creating a sample project with Visual Studio's project wizard? The sample project is a text editor with menu, styling, Unicode (UTF16) support. Unicode support is just a checkbox. You can select plain text, RTF, HTML editor views from combos.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos actually #define mstring std::string.

Comment: The only problem you may encounter is that Windows works natively with UTF16LE. Strings are either UTF16 Unicode or encoded. With UTF8 strings though, you can't tell whether they are UTF8 or ASCII unless you scan the entire string for non-ASCII characters. You'll have to *convert* the UTF8 string to UTF16 before passing it to any system function. Definitely before displaying it.

Comment: Then `#undef mstring std::string`. That's an extremely bad idea. Everyone knows what a `std::string` is

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is a big project and they want to fix this just change few codes.I am junior software engineer(first month).so can you show the way and i am ready to search and learn.

Comment: Then try the wizard-generated sample

Comment: Another thing to consider is that C++ got actual Unicode support and types starting with C++11. There are now `char16_t`, `char32_t` and the corresponding standard types. UTF8 though still has to use the 8-bit types.

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not support UTF-8 encoded path names for `fopen`:

> The `fopen` function opens the file that is specified by `filename`. By
>   default, a narrow filename string is interpreted using the ANSI
>   codepage (`CP_ACP`).

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen).

Instead, a second function, called `_wfopen` is provided, which accepts a wide-character string as path argument.

Similar restrictions apply [when using the C++ fstreams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829364/open-utf8-encoded-filename-in-c-windows) for File I/O.

So the only way for you to solve this is by converting your UTF-8 encoded pathname either to the system codepage or [to a wide character string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148403/utf8-to-from-wide-char-conversion-in-stl).

Comment: Worth noting that a) WIndows is natively Unicode (UTF16 to be exact) which is why you can't pass a UTF8 string and more importantly, b) VC++ uses macros that target Ascii/Unicode functions and types through the `_t` prefix. Using `_tfopen` instead of `fopen()` or `_wfopen()` would have avoided the problem in the first place

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Good point about the `_tfopen` macro. Unfortunately these macros still stem from a time when Unicode-support meant making a binary decision between ASCII and UCS-2, so I am not sure of how much use they are in a codebase that is largely UTF-8 based. In particular I am not sure they would have helped catching this particular mistake, as UTF-8 and ASCII strings share the same types in C.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you explain a) pls? i dont get it

Comment: And still do, even though C++ got char16_ and char32_t in C++ 11. Such codebases are generally in trouble when they encounter non-UTF8 text. As in all non-English text files, saved using the end user's native encoding. A case where you *can't* just force everything to be treated as UTF8 with an environment variable

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have to read contains like that "C:\Users\cagri.ozcan\Desktop\ç\SysData" in sysdatapath.dat file.This file created manually.(notepad++)

Comment: @cevapsızcagri Windows uses 2-byte Unicode since the first NT version. Otherwise it *wouldn't* be used all over the world, especially not in Eastern Europe and Asia. Ascii functions are only for convenience and migrating older code. A string is either Unicode or it isn't. The *file system, NTFS* supports Unicode paths. Only the *IO functions* work with ASCII, again for convenience. Nowadays, and for the last 10 years I'd say, if some code uses ASCII on Windows, there's a serious bug. Unless it's the tax service where they don't care /1

Comment: @cevapsızcagri UTF16 can be detected very easily, even when you enter ANSI characters - the first byte of every character is always null. UTF8 though is indistinguishable from some ASCII string. It may be exactly the same if contains latin characters, or it may contain characters that may be valid in an ASCII codepage. Which means, mixing UTF8 and ASCII is error-prone. You can treat *all* strings as UTF8, but then your code will fail if you try to load a file encoded with a local codepage /2

Comment: @cevapsızcagri (some) Linux applications get away with it by simply ignoring the local use case -just set an environment variable to UTF8. Never mind that Greek company that had to sell Turkish pillows to Bulgaria (true story). 4 codepages (3 local + 1 English) for the price of 1. /3

Comment: @cevapsızcagri in Windows, there *should* be no ambiguity. Convert everything to Unicode when loading. You only care about the codepage when importing/exporting text. The language itself will complain if you forget to convert. Otherwise, you *have* to keep track of the codepage, always. Typically, this means that your code should accept a locale parameter. Or you can assume that your app will use `char` ASCII throughout and deal with codepages at the edges, without any support from the language or OS.

Comment: @ComicSansMS one can see the quaint UTF16/UTF8/ASCII dance performed live with R on Windows, R-Studio didn't store scripts as UTF8 by default until recently, the language and some packages are (mostly) Unicode, some packages are plain ASCII and some are ... half-and-half. The `write` function works with Unicode while `read` is ASCII, mangling the text.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OMG really so much deeply information for beginner junior. I am really confused :) but really thnx for your caring and your answers.

Answer (score 0):

fopen usually reads unicode chars. try to change the files encoding