# C++ - How to convert String to wchar_t (Cyrillic)

Tags: c++, string, wchar-t

I need to convert a `string` to a `wchar_t`.  I have tried a lot of different approaches, but I keep having problems with Cyrillic text. When using `wcout` to debug, I keep getting wrong output, but when just using Latin characters, no problems arise.

So how can I convert a `string` containing Cyrillic characters to a `wchar_t`?

**upd:** 
I found the problem, I made a mistake when used `wcout` to debug,  I all time was getting wrong output. But i manually  rechecked character codes and it is realy `UTF-16`.  I dont know how to make correct output `UTF-16` into console by `wcout`, but it is not so important for me.

Comment: Why do you need `wchar_t` on Linux? What's wrong with UTF-8?

Comment: i have external library which use wchar_t as input  parameters.

Comment: I am not an expert on C++, but I don't agree this is a bad question. The question is quite clear: How do I convert one type to another properly.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried creating a `std::wstring` from the string then going to a `wchar_t`?

Comment: Could you add some code to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you also need to know size of `wchar_t` that that library requires. It may be 16 or 32 bits on different systems. Then you can use [`std::wstring_convert::from_bytes`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert/from_bytes). [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153935/how-to-convert-utf-8-stdstring-to-utf-16-stdwstring) can also be useful for you.

Comment: I tried it before, but had the same result. But now i found the my mistake and it is working for me, thanks.