# Looking for c++ equivalent for _wfindfirst for char16_t

Tags: unicode, wchar-t, equivalent, findfirst, char16-t

I have filenames using `char16_t` characters:

```
char16_t Text[2560] = u"ThisIsTheFileName.txt";
char16_t const* Filename = Text;
```

How can I check if the file exists already? I know that I can do so for `wchar_t` using `_wfindfirst()`. But I need `char16_t` here.

**Is there an equivalent function to `_wfindfirst()` for `char16_t`?**

Background for this is that I need to work with Unicode characters and want my code working on Linux (32-bit) as well as on other platforms (16-bit).

Comment: wfindfirst() is highly specific to the Microsoft CRT and Windows, so you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findfirst()` is the counterpart to `_wfindfirst()`.

However, both `findfirst()` and `_wfindfirst()` are specific to Windows. `findfirst()` accepts ANSI (outdated legacy stuff). `_wfindfirst()` accepts UTF-16 in the form of `wchar_t` (which is not exactly the same thing as `char16_t`).

ANSI and UTF-16 are generally not used on Linux. `findfirst()`/`_wfindfirst()` are not included in the gcc compiler.

Linux uses UTF-8 for its Unicode format. You can use `access()` to check for file permission, or use `opendir()`/`readdir()`/`closedir()` as the equivalent to `findfirst()`.

If you have a UTF-16 filename from Windows, you can convert the name to UTF-8, and use the UTF-8 name in Linux. See [How to convert UTF-8 std::string to UTF-16 std::wstring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153935/)

Consider using [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) in C++17 or higher.

Note that a Windows or Linux executable is 32-bit or 64-bit, that doesn't have anything to do with the character set. Some very old systems are 16-bit, you probably don't come across them.