# What C++ string classes/systems exist that have good unicode support and a decent interface?

Tags: c++

Using strings in C++ development is always a bit more complicated than in languages like Java or scripting languages. I think some of the complexity comes from a performance focus in C++ and some is just historical.

I know of the following major string systems and would like to find out if there are others and what specific drawbacks they have vs. each other:

- ICU : http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings#TOC-Using-Unicode-Strings-in-C-
- GLib::ustring : http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-basics-ustring.html.en
- MFC CString : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea%28VS.100%29.aspx
- std::basic_string : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string
- QT QString : http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qstring.html#details

I'll admit that there can be no definite answer, but I think SOs voting system in uniquely suited to show the preferences (and thus the validity of arguments) of people actually using a certain string system.

---

Added from answers:

- UFT8-CPP : http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If you want votes, make this community wiki.

Comment: @Neil : Have done so. Makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Using strings in C++ development is
>   always a bit more complicated than in
>   languages like Java or scripting
>   languages. I think some of the
>   complexity comes from a performance
>   focus in C++ and some is just
>   historical.

I'd say it's *all* historical.  In particular, two pieces of history:

- C was developed back in the days when everyone ([even Japan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0201)) was using a 7-bit or 8-bit character encoding.  Because of this, the concepts of `char` and "byte" are hopelessly confounded.
- C++ programmers quickly recognized the desirability of having a string class rather than just raw `char*`.  Unfortunately, they had to wait 15 years for one to be officially standardized.  In the meantime, people wrote their own string classes that we're still stuck with today.

Anyhow, I've used two of the classes you mentioned:

### MFC CString

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea%28VS.71%29.aspx)

There are actually two `CString` classes: `CStringA` uses `char` with "ANSI" encoding, and `CStringW` uses `wchar_t` with UTF-16 encoding.  `CString` is a typedef of one of them depending on a preprocessor macro.  (**Lots** of things in Windows come in "ANSI" and "Unicode" versions.)

You *could* use UTF-8 for the `char`-based version, but this has the problem that Microsoft refuses to support "UTF-8" as an ANSI code page.  Thus, functions like `Trim(const char* pszTargets)`, which depend on being able to recognize character boundaries, won't work correctly if you use them with non-ASCII characters.

Since UTF-16 is natively supported, you'll probably prefer the `wchar_t`-based version.

Both CString classes have a fairly convenient [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abzc9989%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), including a printf-like `Format` function.  Plus the ability to *pass* CString objects to this varags function, due to the way the class is implemented.

The main disadvantages are:

- Slow performance for very large strings.  (Last I checked, anyway.)
- Lack of integration with the C++ standard library.  No iterators, not even `<<` and `>>` for streams.
- It's Windows-only.

(That last point has caused me *much* frustration since I got put in charge of porting our code to Linux.  Our company wrote our own string class that's a clone of CString but cross-platform.)

### std::basic_string

The good thing about [`basic_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) is that it's the standard.

The bad thing about it is that it doesn't have Unicode support.  OTOH, it doesn't actively *not* support Unicode, as it lacks member functions like `upper()` / `lower()` that would depend on the character encoding.  In that sense, it's really more of a "dynamic array of code units" than a "string".

There are libraries that let you use `std::string` with UTF-8, such as the above-mentioned [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) and some of the functions in the [Poco](http://pocoproject.org) library.

For which size characters to use, see [std::wstring vs std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring).

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look at [UTF8-CPP: UTF-8 with C++ in a Portable Way](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/)

It is very lean and has a really neat C++ interface, using the standard std::string as container for the string data, thus avoiding lots of casts for other-than-unicode operations, and providing simple additional functions for unicode handling.

Comment: This is the best drop-in solution I've found. It integrates beautifully with existing C++ tools and idioms, and provides unchecked operations for improved performance.

Answer (score 1):

Some random thoughts:

- `std::basic_string`: No unicode support at all, not really usable for platform-independent applications. If your code is intended for a specific platform, you can usually use `std::wstring` (Windows, UTF-16) or `std::string` (Unix-like systems, UTF-8) for storing Unicode strings, but everything else (encodings, character properties, Unicode algorithms...) is completely absent.
- ICU: Idiosyncratic interface that doesn't blend well with STL algorithms (e.g., a Java-style iterator). Apart from that, ICU seems to be an industry standard and is quite extensive. Uses UTF-16 mainly, but supports other encodings.
- Qt: Nice interface that is both practical and STL compatible. Uses UTF-16 internally. Would probably be my first choice if I had to write platform-independent applications in C++.
- GLib, MFC: Don't know about those.
- Platform-dependent facilities: For very basic tasks (e.g., encodings), you can get along with these (e.g. iconv on Unix-like systems, `MultiByteToWideChar` on Windows). Pro: No external library required.

Comment: I use std::string cross-platform all the time.

Comment: But then you have to convert to UTF-16 every time you call an OS function.

Comment: @Phillip Not on any OS I use (Windows, Linux, UNIX, Solaris)

Comment: Please elaborate. All Windows API functions accept only UTF-16, so somewhere there must exist an UTF-8 ↔ UTF-16 conversion.

Comment: @philip: last time I checked the ASCII version of all winapi functions didn't magically disappear. As long as there's no weird characters in the strings you're using on an OS level, no need for fancy Unicode.

Comment: I think it depends. File operations without Unicode support *are* no-go IMHO. But there are other APIs where not using Unicode may be OK.

Comment: @Phillip I don't use Unicode for anything, and don't feel I am missing out.

Comment: @Phillip: Only if you are doing internationalization.

Comment: I find it interesting how many people keep on using the obsolete 8-bit API. I wish Microsoft had abolished this API long time ago.

Comment: ICU has some support for std::string now, and an increasing number of UTF-8 APIs, as well as efficient routines/macros for converting between UTFs.

Comment: @Philipp: I'm not really surprised.  The problem with UTF-16 is that you have to change a zillion lines of old code that uses `char` strings.  And then you *still* have a variable-length encoding.  I wish Windows had taken the UTF-8 approach like the Unix-like OSes did.