# Character encoding problem

Tags: c++, unicode

Greetings,

I'm developing a project in C++ where I want to use characters like `á é õ` and `┌ ─ ┐ │` to draw a couple of nice frames. My doubt resides in what I should change in my code/project settings since, without any kind of modifications, the console just prints pseudo-random characters.

I know that the above characters are defined in the character set Code page 437 aka Extended ASCII, but what I should do know?

After some research, I included the instruction `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");` and now I can print accented characters (à é õ) but can't print the borders.

Also, should I use `char` and `string` or `wchar` and `wstring` to use these characters?

Thanks

Comment: Your application may be using a specific local. But what local/character encoding is the terminal using to display the characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do it would be to use wchar and wstring for the characters - they are meant for locale-independant string operations and are defined as UTF-16 in Windows and as UTF-32 in Linux.

Note that you need to use the proper functions, for example `wprintf` instead of `printf`... If you're using `iostream`, I think that should work out-of-the-box with wstrings.

**EDIT:** Note that it is not required for `wchar_t` to be unicode (in practice, it often is). If `wchar_t` (and thus, `wstring`) is unicode, then the C99 standard (and therefore most likely the C++ standard) states that `__STDC_ISO_10646__` is to be defined.

In other words, if `__STDC_ISO_10646__` is defined, then the `wchar_t` is unicode -- as for the exact type (UTF-16 or UTF-32), you can use a sizeof(wchar_t).

Comment: In C++ (which is based on C89, not C99), what encoding `wchar_t` and `std::wstring` have is an implementation detail, although what you state for Windows/Linux is the common case. For stream IO, use `std::wcout`, `std::wcin` etc.

Comment: I removed the `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");` since wchar and wstring are locale-independant. But now, the compiler outputs the error `converting to execution character set: Illegal byte sequence` with operations like `std::wstring maintenance = L"Manutenção";` What's happening?

Comment: @sbi: Same goes for C99, it is implementation-dependant - but, as I said `__STDC_ISO_10646__` is defined if whatever wchar_t is, is some form of Unicode.

Comment: @renatorodrigues: Hm, I'm not sure what could be causing that, to be quite honest... **EDIT:** Maybe LC_CTYPE also refers to the locale of string literals? As in, the current locale you're editing with. That's more or less a wild guess though.

Comment: IIUC, `__STDC_ISO_10646__` is a _C99_ macro. It _might_ be defined by a C++ compiler, but doesn't have to, because C++ doesn't officially know about C99.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`wchar_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring)

Answer (score 0):

To see which Unicode characters to use look up http://unicode.org/charts/ and search for "Box Drawing". That set includes the characters that are in CP 437, but also many others. Next question is whether your device can show some or all of these.