# What is the difference between "UTF-16" and "std::wstring"?

Tags: c++, unicode, stl, utf-16

Is there any difference between these two string storage formats?

Comment: there's a pretty good answer to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring/402918#402918

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`std::wstring` is a container of `wchar_t`. The size of `wchar_t` is not specified—Windows compilers tend to use a 16-bit type, Unix compilers a 32-bit type.

[UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) is a way of encoding sequences of Unicode code points in sequences of 16-bit integers.

Using Visual Studio, if you use wide character literals (e.g. `L"Hello World"`) that contain no characters outside of the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), you'll end up with UTF-16, but mostly the two concepts are unrelated. If you use characters outside the BMP, `std::wstring` will not translate [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF) into Unicode code points for you, even if `wchar_t` is 16 bits.

Comment: Do you mean that std::wstring is the same with UTF-16 for only the non-BMP unicode character when used in Windows operating system?

Comment: No. std::wstring is just a container of integers. The encoding of the container depends entirely on the data you insert into the container.

Comment: +1: For people unfamiliar with UTF it may be wise to define BMP.

Comment: Your last paragraph is the answer to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

UTF-16 is a specific Unicode encoding. `std::wstring` is a string implementation that uses `wchar_t` as its underlying type for storing each character. (In contrast, regular `std::string` uses `char`).

The encoding used with [`wchar_t`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character#C.2FC.2B.2B) does not necessarily have to be UTF-16—it could also be UTF-32 for example.

Comment: It could also be UCS-2 or S-JIS or Big 5 or ... well, anything.

Answer (score 3):

UTF-16 is a concept of text represented in 16-bit elements but an actual textual character may consist of more than one element

std::wstring is just a collection of these elements, and is a class primarily concerned with their storage.

The elements in a wstring, wchar_t is at least 16-bits but could be 32 bits.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail, like giving an example. For instance the character 'A' is stored in std::wstring like "0x0041". How is it stored in UTF-16 format?

Comment: 16-**byte** ?? woah that's a hardcore character encoding

Comment: @Inverse: That's why everyone should just use ASCII, there wouldn't be so much grief on memory use ;)

Comment: For those who may not understand the humor in the above comments, [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) is a 16-***bit*** Unicode encoding. Also, in UTF-16, a character that is defined using more than one 16-bit element is done so via [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF).