# Converting C++ std::wstring to utf8 with std::codecvt_xxx

Tags: c++, string, windows, utf-8, widechar

C++11 has tools to convert wide char strings `std::wstring` from/to utf8 representation: `std::codecvt`, `std::codecvt_utf8`, `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16` etc.

Which one is usable by Windows app to convert regular wide char Windows strings `std::wstring` to utf8 `std::string`? Is it always works without configuring locales?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert wstring to string encoded in UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358870/convert-wstring-to-string-encoded-in-utf-8)

Comment: @IInspectable I posted this question after reading the page you mentioned ))) I do not see a clear answer to my question on that page

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12903901/1889329) not answer your question? According to a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358870/convert-wstring-to-string-encoded-in-utf-8#comment32601904_12903901) *"[t]his works for Windows if you use VS2012 or later"*.

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

Depends how you convert them.
You need to specify the source encoding type and the target encoding type.
`wstring` is not a format, it just defines a data type.

Now usually when one says "Unicode", one means `UTF16` which is what **Microsoft Windows** uses, and that is usuasly what `wstring` contains.

So, the right way to convert from UTF8 to UTF16:

```
     std::string utf8String = "blah blah";

     std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> convert;
     std::wstring utf16String = convert.from_bytes( utf8String );
```

And the other way around:

```
     std::wstring utf16String = "blah blah";

     std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> convert;
     std::string utf8String = convert.to_bytes( utf16String );
```

And to add to the confusion:
When you use `std::string` on a **windows** platform (like when you use a multibyte compilation), It's NOT **UTF8**. They use **ANSI**.
More specifically, the default encoding language your windows is using.

Also, note that [wstring is not exactly the same as UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247236/what-is-the-difference-between-utf-16-and-stdwstring).

When compiling in Unicode the windows API commands expect these formats:

Command**A** - **multibyte** - `ANSI`
Command**W** - **Unicode** - `UTF16`

Comment: *"usually when one says "Unicode", one means UTF16"* - Uhm... When one says "Unicode" I would hope that one knows Unicode, and doesn't confuse the standard with an arbitrary encoding. *"When you use std::string on a windows platform [...], It's NOT UTF8. They use ANSI."* - The character encoding used for `std::string` is determined by the implementation (i.e. compiler), not the target platform. You can write a compiler that uses UTF-8 encoding for `std::string` on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that `std::codecvt_utf8` works well for conversion `std::wstring` -> `utf8`. It passed all my tests. (Windows app, Visual Studio 2015, Windows 8 with EN locale)

I needed a way to convert filenames to UTF8. Therefore my test is about filenames.

In my app I use `boost::filesystem::path` 1.60.0 to deal with file path. It works well, but not able to convert filenames to UTF8 properly. 
Internally Windows version of `boost::filesystem::path` uses `std::wstring` to store the file path. Unfortunately, build-in conversion to `std::string` works bad.

Test case:

- create file with mixed symbols `c:\test\皀皁皂皃的` (some random Asian symbols)
- scan dir with `boost::filesystem::directory_iterator`, get `boost::filesystem::path` for the file
- convert it to the `std::string` via build-in conversion `filenamePath.string()`
- you get `c:\test\?????`. Asian symbols converted to '?'. Not good.

`boost::filesystem` uses `std::codecvt` internally. It doesn't work for conversion `std::wstring` -> `std::string`.

Instead of build-in `boost::filesystem::path` conversion you can define conversion function as this ([original snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12903901/1889329)):

```
std::string utf8_to_wstring(const std::wstring & str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
    return myconv.to_bytes(str);
}
```

Then you can convert filepath to UTF8 easily: `utf8_to_wstring(filenamePath.wstring())`. It works perfectly.

It works for any filepath. I tested ASCII strings `c:\test\test_file`, Asian strings `c:\test\皀皁皂皃的`, Russian strings `c:\test\абвгд`, mixed strings `c:\test\test_皀皁皂皃的`, `c:\test\test_абвгд`, `c:\test\test_皀皁皂皃的_абвгд`. For every string I receive valid UTF8 representation.