# Difference and conversions between wchar_t for Linux and for Windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, wchar

I understand from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383946/conflicts-definition-of-wchar-t-string-in-c-standard-and-windows-implementati) and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/vclanguage/thread/e00358e5-1dab-4c92-8676-112445494f9e) thread that in Windows, wchar_t is 16-bit & for Linux, wchar_t is 32 bit.

I have a client-server architecture (using just pipes - not sockets)- where my server is Windows based and client is Linux.

Server has a API to retrieve hostname from client. When the client is Windows based, it could just do GetComputerNameW and return Wide-String. 
However, when the client is Linux based, things get messy.

As a first naive approach, I used mbstowcs() hoping to return wchar_t* to Windows server-side.
However, this LPWSTR (I have typedef wchar_t* LPWSTR on my linux clinet side) is not recognizable on Windows since it expects its wchar_t to be 16-bit.

So, converting the output of gethostname() on linux - which is in char* to unsigned short (16-bit) my only option?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What is your "on-the-wire" format for text ?

Comment: use libicu. You will need to convert from UCS-2 windows to UCS-4 Linux, UTF-8 linux file system, etc.

Comment: How about trying [UTF-8 Everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/)? Your linux code will be clean, and the windows part will be easily interoperable with the rest of your application.

Answer (score 6):

You will have to decide on the actual protocol on how to transport the data across the wire. Several options here although probably UTF-8 is usually the most sensible one - also that means that under linux you can basically just use the data as-is (no reason to use wchar_t to begin with, although you obviously can convert it into whatever you want).

Under Windows you will have to convert the UTF-8 into UTF-16 (yes not exactly, but oh well) which windows wants and if you want to send data you have to convert it to UTF-8. Luckily windows provides [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) respectively [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for exactly these purposes.

Obviously you can decide on any encoding you want to not necessarily UTF-8, the process is the same: When receiving data convert it to the native format of the OS, when sending convert it to your on-wire encoding. [iconv](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/iconv.3.html) works on linux if you don't use utf-8.

Comment: how you will display UTF-8 on linux, GUI?

Comment: @neagoegab That pretty much depends on which graphics library you're actually using doesn't it? But QT for example allows users to use UTF-8 just fine even if it internally uses UTF-16 to represent the data.

Answer (score 2):

You are best off choosing a standard character encoding for the data you send over the pipe, and then require all machines to send their data using that encoding.

Windows uses UTF-16LE, so you could choose to use UTF-16LE over the pipe and then Windows machines can send their UTF-16LE encoded strings as-is, but Linux machines would have to convert to/from UTF-16LE as needed.

Or you could choose UTF-8 instead, which would reduce network bandwidth, but both Windows and Linux machines would have to convert to/from UTF-8 as neded.  For network communications, UTF-8 would be the better choice.

On Windows, you can use `MultiByteToWideChar()` and `WideCharToMultiByte()` with the `CP_UTF8` codepage.

In Linux, use the `iconv()` API so you can specify the UTF-8 charset for encoding/decoding.

Comment: Don't really see any reason to use `wchar_t` under linux to begin with. Only causes problems and I can't think of many APIs that don't use UTF-8 and just return `char*` to begin with.