# How do I tell a wstring that a string I am feeding it is already a wstring?

Tags: c++, stl, wstring

I am using a std::string as a text buffer. Then, I am sure the data contained in that buffer is UTF-16 (i.e. it is really a std::wstring). **How can I coerce a std::string into a std::wstring?** The std::string is a misnomer, the data is really a wstring.

Comment: `std::string` ≠ binary buffer!  Use a more appropriate data type like `std::vector<uint8_t>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using a `std::vector<char>` instead of a `std::string`.  It's the correct container when you want "a contiguous sequence of bytes."

With a `std::vector` source container, the code is rather straightforward, assuming you really just want to reinterpret the data (i.e., you really just want to treat the bytes as if they were a sequence of `wchar_t`):

```
std::vector<char> v = get_my_wstring_character_data();
if (v.size() % sizeof (wchar_t) != 0)
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid wstring length");

std::wstring ws(reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(&v[0]), 
                reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(&v[0] + v.size()));
```

If your source is a `std::string`, this same approach will work if you can guarantee that the implementation of `std::string` you are using stores its characters contiguously.  In practice, this is always the case.

Comment: "In practice, this is always the case." You don't know how many hours I've wasted on theory. Practice IS the library and greatly aids implementation. Thanks.

Comment: Do heed Jon's warning, though:  the size of `wchar_t` and how it represents characters are both implementation-defined, so if you are writing code that needs to run on multiple platforms, you can't rely on it having a particular size and form.

Comment: `v.data()` is an pointer to a contiguous `char[]` which can be used portably instead of `&v[0]`. You of course don't solve the `wchar_t =?= UTF-16` issue with that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that `std::wstring` stores/interprets byte arrays as UTF-16 (although it *happens* to do that in Windows). Check out this question: [std::wstring VS std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/402283/50079)

Therefore I would advise you to rethink the idea of constructing a `std::wstring` from a UTF-16 encoded byte array unless you are sure your application will only ever be compiled with MSVC.

Comment: The particular code in question deals with Win32 API's which is why I chose `std::wstring` in the first place. I am a unix nut, didn't even know about wstring until in MSVC debugger ;)