# Most basic way to open a file in Windows

Tags: windows

I am writing a library that will be statically linked (to other libraries or to applications).  I want to make my library as small as possible.  My library needs to read a file; the name of the file will be known in advance and contains only ASCII characters.  My library will have absolutely no user interface or GUI code; it's just functions to be called.

What function should I call to open my file, with the linker bringing in as little additional code as possible?

Presumably `CreateFile()` is a basic built-in Windows feature that lives in a shared library.  So, should I just use `CreateFileA()` (to avoid a conversion to wide char)?

For `CreateFileA()` I will need to include `Windows.h`; will this increase the size of my library?  If so, does defining `WINDOWS_LEAN_AND_MEAN` help?

Should I just use `_open()`?  Or, I guess it should be `_sopen_s()` now?

Comment: Did you know all the functions that end with `A` are just wrappers for the `W` ones?

Comment: Why not just ANSI C fiel functions?: `fopen`, `fread`, etc.

Comment: @JesseGood, I don't grasp the point behind your comment.  Okay, functions that end in `A` are wrappers; and this affects my problem... how?

Comment: @Linuxios, I'm going for minimum size.  If `fopen()` and friends would make my library just as small as `CreateFileA()` then I will cheerfully use them; I prefer the *NIX functions to the native Windows functions almost always.

Comment: @steveha: It's not directly related but since the `A` functions incur overhead(they convert from ASCII to Unicode and then call the `W` functions), it would be better to use the `W` functions to begin with.

Comment: This is a C++ question, but I recommend reading [std::wstring VS std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring) as it talks about windows. (Quote: `if you work on Windows, you badly want to use wchar_t`).

Comment: @JesseGood, I don't think I care about the overhead of a single `char` string to `wchar_t` string conversion, for reading a single file.  But you did push me into the realization that I can just declare the filename string with the `_T()` macro or even as an `L""` literal, so I don't need to do any runtime conversion from `char` to `wchar_t`.  So perhaps I'll use `CreateFileW()` after all; why not?  I guess if I was really obsessed with saving bytes, I'd object to the filename string using two bytes per character instead of one, but I think that should be okay!

Comment: @Joey, I'm afraid I don't follow you.  I thought I had explained quite thoroughly in my question: my library needs to read one file with a known filename, that filename contains only basic ASCII characters, and the library should be as small as possible.  It seems like a pretty specific problem domain.  So I don't understand where "all users" come in, and I don't understand what it means to "sacrifice Unicode" in this context.

Comment: @JesseGood: For the OP's problem, "use W functions" really is not applicable, as it makes all strings twice as long as necessary. Besides, "you badly want to use wchar_t" is not generally true either. There are a some excellent reasons for not using wchar_t under Windows, doing so is just the easiest thing API-wise. That does not mean it's the best.

Comment: @Damon: Concerning your comment `There are a some excellent reasons for not using wchar_t under Windows`, do you have any information or examples backing this claim up?

Comment: @JesseGood: Though I can see this going totally off-topic, one good reason is that UTF16 has all the disadvantages of UTF8 plus some others (e.g. not compatible with standard libc character functions) and uses ~2x the memory for non-Southeast-Asian languages. OTOH, if you _need_ non-BMP, it doesn't do it "properly" either. The often cited advantage of deterministic string length is a lie. Whether or not Windows internally converts one into the other is irrelevant. The conversion overhead is ridiculous compared to the overhead that most Win32 API funcs already have anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_open and it's derivatives use the standard c library, which will typical add size to your library. CreateFile is the way to go. A or W depends if you need to link in Unicode, which will depend on what you're linking with.

Comment: +1. The C library is not "standard" on Windows, so you'd have to statically link it - = larger binary. If only concern is size, A or W won't make a difference, all functions will come from external DLLs.

Comment: @vanza -- Visual C does so much that is magical and automatic... how can I tell whether or not Visual C slurped in the standard C library?  For example, if I `#include <stdlib.h>` to get types like `size_t` will that make Visual C slurp in the library, or would I actually need to reference a library function so the linker would link in the library?  Visual C doesn't even show me the actual output from the linker, just a sanitized status listing like this:  `Foo.vcxproj -> C:\Users\steveha\Project\Debug\foo.lib`

Comment: @steveha: you need to reference a symbol from the library to need to link the library. Type definitions are just in header files, not the library. Since you're creating a static library, I don't think the linker will require you to link msvcrt right away - just when an application statically links your library and creates its own DLL or EXE.

Comment: @vanza -- Makes sense.  I'm just suspicious of Visual C since it does so much automatically and hides so much!