# std::string, wstring, u16/32string clarification

Tags: c++, string, unicode, std

My current understanding of the difference between `std::string` and `std::wstring` is simply the buffer's type; namely, `char` vs `wchar_t`, respectively.

I've also read that most (if not all) linux distros use `char` for any and all strings, both ASCII as well as UTF, where Windows is the primary OS that uses `wchar_t` anymore.

However, there are a few more string types that I want to get straight in my head: `u16string` and `u32string`, which are strings with 2-byte and 4-byte buffers, respectively.

So, my question is this:

On platforms with `sizeof(wchar_t) == 2`, is `std::wstring` functionally equivalent to `std::u16string`, as well as platforms with `sizeof(wchar_t) == 4` and `std::u32string`?

Comment: there is another similar question on SO about string/wstring [here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring>

Comment: @FloreaMarian Not really - that question is asking the difference between `string` and `wstring`. I'm asking whether or not `wstring` is the same as `u16string` or `u32string` depending on the size of `wchar_t`.

Comment: see http://utf8everywhere.org

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky Just wanted to thank you almost 2 years later for that link. It completely changed how I design some of my software.

Comment: I am happy! Let's spread the better way. http://utf8everywhere.org FTW :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The difference is that the details of `char` and `wchar_t` are implementation defined, while the encoding of `char16_t` and `char32_t` are explicitly defined by the C++11 standard.

This means that `wstring` is *likely* to store the same data as either `u16string` or `u32string`, but we don't know which one. And it is allowed for some odd implementation to make them all different, as the size and encoding of the old char types are just not defined by the standard.

Comment: `wstring` will *never* be the same as those other string types. The standard *requires* `wchar_t` to be a distinct type from `char16_t` and `char32_t`. They may in fact have the same underlying type and the same encoding, but `is_same<wstring, u16string>` will *never* be `true` for any valid C++ implementation.

Comment: "The same" here means "functionally equivalent", like it says in the question. If `sizeof(wchar_t) == 4` you will very likely get the same result from using either a `wstring` or a `u32string`.