# convert wchar_t to char c++

Tags: c++, char, wchar-t

I use mingw compiler.
How to convert `wchar_t` to `char` ?

```
Data(HWND hwnd,  wchar_t szFileName[MAX_PATH])
{
    string sIn;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(szFileName);
    infile.seekg(0,ios::beg);

    // fill vector with file rows
    while ( getline(infile,sIn ) )
    {
       fileRows.push_back(sIn);
    }
}
```

I would like to convert wchar_t szFileName to char szFileNameChar.

Comment: [`std::wstring_convert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) should help.

Comment: Bad question. char and wchar don't describe the encoding of what is stored. What you need to ask is what is the encoding of the text in your strings (both char and wchar_t versions). Once you have this then we can discuss how to convert from one to the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string str("i'm char[]");
wstring wstr(str.begin(), str.end());

wstring wstr(L"i'm wchar_t[]");
string str(wstr.begin(), wstr.end());
```

To see a detailed explanation, please refer to the following post: 
[std::wstring VS std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring)

Comment: It might work for ASCII text, but this is very locale-dependant and won't work for some character encodings.