# LPWSTR to std::string?

Tags: c++

Is there a simple way to convert a LPWSTR to std::string?

My problem: I have a filepath as an LPWSTR and I want to use the methods from the string class to manipulate the path.

Maybe another way to answer my problem: Are there alternate methods for the LPWSTR that are found in the string class?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring?rq=1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To manipulate wide character strings, use `std::wstring` which is a wide character string.

Comment: a copde snippet illustrating the use of wstring would be nice