# How to handle string and wstring in one project

Tags: c++, string, unicode, wstring

I am writing code that uses string and the code needs to be compiled alongside other projects. Some of these projects are using Unicode and some others using multi byte string.

How can  write my code in a way that it can be compiled in both configuration?

For example I know that TCHAR is a macro that expand to suitable char based on configuration. Is there any similar things for string/wstring?

What is the best practise on using string/wstring when portability is important?

Comment: `TCHAR` is terrible nowadays, but take a closer look at what `std::string` really is.

Comment: "How to handel string" - Handel is [something (someone) else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Friedrich_H%C3%A4ndel). The word you're looking for is "handle".

Comment: @chris: What is the best practice? Should I stick to Unicode? Is it supported everywhere?

Comment: @mans, There's [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring?rq=1), there's http://utf8everywhere.org. Look around and you'll find a few differing opinions, but should be able to have some idea at least.

Comment: @chris what is std:sring? How can I read more about what is inside? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @mans, I was referring to [a reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), specifically the type-definition table, keeping in mind `TCHAR` is one or the other.

Comment: `TCHAR` is a Microsoft-ism. Whatever it does is not portable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `std::wstring` to store your strings, then convert the strings to what the libraries that you are using is requesting as needed.