# How do I convert wchar_t* to string?

Tags: c++, string, converters, wchar-t

I am new to C++.

And I am trying to convert wchar_t* to string.

I cannot use wstring in condition.

I have code below:

```
wchar_t *wide   = L"中文";
wstring ret     = wstring( wide );
string str2( ret.begin(), ret.end() );
```

But str2 returns some strange characters.

Where do I have to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring

Comment: That's because `str2` is of type `string` which holds `char`s; you're forcing `wchar_t` data on `char`, there'll be data loss.

Comment: why can't you use wstring in a condition?

Comment: @GrahamGriffiths Coz, I cannot find to concat string(which is produced before this line) and wstring.

Comment: you can create a wstring from a string in the same way you are creating a string from a wstring - although it is only safe / correct for single byte characters. Then you can concatenate your two wstrings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to do it backwards. Instead of truncating wide characters to `char`s (which is very lossy), expand your `char`s to wide characters.

That is, transform your `std::string` into an `std::wstring` and concatenate the two `std::wstring`s.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what platform you're targeting. If you're on Windows platform you can call WideCharToMultiByte API function. Refer to MSDN for documentation.

If you're on Linux, I think you can use libiconv functions, try google.

Of course there is a port of libiconv for Windows.

In general this is a quite complex topic for a new beginners if you know nothing about character encodings - there are a lot of background knowledge to have to learn.