# Convert char* to Unicode std::string

Tags: c++, unicode, ascii, std

I've been programming many years but am very new to the the `std` namespace and the `std::string` class.

I'm writing code to read the value from `Gdiplus::PropertyItem::value`, which is `char *`.

What is the most accepted way to convert this `char *` value to `string`, which in my case is a Unicode string?

Comment: see http://utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mentioning `string` but you say it's a Unicode string. So then I suppose you mean `wstring`. You could use the [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to convert between the two. Something like this:

```
std::string str(...);
int size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), NULL, 0);
std::wstring wstr(size, 0 );
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &wstr[0], size);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to MFC and `CString`, which is ASCII or Unicode depending on build settings. So, yes, it looks like I need `std::wstring`. But I'm blown away that I need to use raw Windows API for this and that `std::wstring` doesn't offer even a helper here.

Comment: @JonathanWood wstring vs string. Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/402918/1866301