# Converting constant char pointer to LPCTSTR

Tags: c++

I am attempting to port some code from a a visual studio project to mingw.
The compiler is pointing out an undefined reference error in which it assumes the second parameter is a `wchar_t const*`. I have both `_UNICODE` and 
`UNICODE` defined in my project

```
undefined reference to `CBaseVideoRenderer::CBaseVideoRenderer(_GUID const&, wchar_t const*, IUnknown*, long*)'
```

Here is the code I am using

The constructor of the base class is this

```
  CBaseVideoRenderer(REFCLSID RenderClass,LPCTSTR pName, LPUNKNOWN pUnk,      
                        HRESULT *phr);
```

This is how its being initiated in the base class

```
MemRenderer::MemRenderer(LPUNKNOWN ptr, HRESULT *hr, OutputBuffer *buffer)
    : CBaseVideoRenderer(__uuidof(CLSID_MemRenderer), NAME("MemRenderer"), ptr, hr)
```

Now I am getting the error on the above statment saying

```
  undefined reference to `CBaseVideoRenderer::CBaseVideoRenderer(_GUID const&, wchar_t const*, IUnknown*, long*)'
```

My question is why am I getting that error ? I looked up LPCTSTR and it seems to be a constant char pointer so I tried this too

```
 MemRenderer::MemRenderer(LPUNKNOWN ptr, HRESULT *hr, OutputBuffer *buffer)
        : CBaseVideoRenderer(__uuidof(CLSID_MemRenderer), "MemRenderer", ptr, hr)
```

However I get the error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'CBaseVideoRenderer::CBaseVideoRenderer(const GUID&, const char [12], IUnknown*&, HRESULT*&)'
    buffer(buffer)
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this issue ?

Comment: See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639114/porting-stdwstring-from-visual-studio-to-mingw-gcc

Comment: The `NAME("MemRenderer")` was accurate, the error was a _linker_ error.  Your code is fine.

Comment: Wait, why is `hr` a `long*` in one code, and a `HRESULT*` in the other?  Also, normally a result named `hr` is a `HRESULT`, and you would pass it by pointer: `&hr`.

Comment: `CBaseVideoRenderer(REFCLSID RenderClass,LPCTSTR pName, LPUNKNOWN pUnk, HRESULT *phr);` is a declaration. I don't suppose you have an *implementation* somewhere to go with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of LPCTSTR depends on whether UTF-16 unicode is enabled as default character type or not.

THis has an impact on litterals:

- `"xxx"`  can be used if no unicode is used.
- `L"xxx"` is to be used if unicode is used

You can find more on the types to be used [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. The NAME macro was not working for some reason and putting an L did the trick