# Unicode string indexing in C++

Tags: c++, string, unicode

I come from python where you can use 'string[10]' to access a character in sequence. And if the string is encoded in Unicode it will give me expected results. However when I use indexing on a string in C++, as long the characters are ASCII it works, but when I use a Unicode character inside the string and use indexing, in the output I'll get an octal representation like /201. 
For example:

```
string ramp = "ÐðŁłŠšÝýÞþŽž";
cout << ramp << "\n";    
cout << ramp[5] << "\n";
```

Output:

```
ÐðŁłŠšÝýÞþŽž
/201
```

Why this is happening and how can I access that character in the string representation or how can I convert the octal representation to the actual character?

Comment: I would recommend using [`std::wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::wcout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout)

Comment: @CoryKramer i would not recommend that unconditionally, see e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring). I would rather recommend using an appropriate library.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Good point. Character encoding makes me doubt everything I think I know about programming :/

Comment: C++ doesn't have any real native Unicode support.

Comment: @Puppy: [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) has. And C++ doesn't have native support for GUIs, or audio processing either, but that doesn't make it any less suited for the job. ;-)

Comment: @Puppy but C++ has L and u8, u16 prefix for Unicode strings

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: That would be `u8`, `u`, and `U`. There is no `u16`. ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Standard C++ is not equipped for proper handling of Unicode, giving you problems like the one you observed.

The problem here is that C++ *predates* Unicode by a comfortable margin. This means that even that string literal of yours will be interpreted in an *implementation-defined* manner because those characters are not defined in the Basic Source Character set (which is, basically, the ASCII-7 characters minus `@`, `$`, and the backtick).

C++98 does not mention Unicode at all. It mentions `wchar_t`, and `wstring` being based on it, specifying `wchar_t` as being capable of "representing any character in the current locale". But that did more damage than good...

Microsoft defined `wchar_t` as 16 bit, which was enough for the Unicode code points *at that time*. However, since then Unicode has been extended beyond the 16-bit range... and Windows' 16-bit `wchar_t` is not "wide" anymore, because you need two of them to represent characters beyond the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) -- and the Microsoft docs are *notoriously* ambiguous as to where `wchar_t` means UTF-16 (multibyte encoding with surrogate pairs) or UCS-2 (wide encoding with no support for characters beyond the BMP).

All the while, a Linux `wchar_t` is 32 bit, which *is* wide enough for UTF-32...

C++11 made significant improvements to the subject, adding `char16_t` and `char32_t` including their associated `string` variants to remove the ambiguity, *but still it is not fully equipped for Unicode operations*.

Just as one example, try to convert e.g. German "Fuß" to uppercase and you will see what I mean. (The single letter `'ß'` would need to expand to `'SS'`, which the standard functions -- handling one character in, one character out at a time -- cannot do.)

However, **[there is help](http://site.icu-project.org/)**. The **International Components for Unicode (ICU)** library *is* fully equipped to handle Unicode in C++. As for specifying special characters in source code, you will have to use `u8""`, `u""`, and `U""` to enforce interpretation of the string literal as UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32 respectively, using octal / hexadecimal escapes or relying on your compiler implementation to handle non-ASCII-7 encodings appropriately.

And even then you will get an integer value for `std::cout << ramp[5]`, because for C++, a character is just an integer with semantic meaning. ICU's `ustream.h` provides `operator<<` overloads for the `icu::UnicodeString` class, but `ramp[5]` is just a 16-bit unsigned integer (1), and people would look askance at you if their `unsigned short` would suddenly be interpreted as characters. You need the [C-API](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustdio_8h.html) `u_fputs()` / `u_printf()` / `u_fprintf()` functions for that.

```
#include <unicode/unistr.h>
#include <unicode/ustream.h>
#include <unicode/ustdio.h>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // make sure your source file is UTF-8 encoded...
    icu::UnicodeString ramp( icu::UnicodeString::fromUTF8( "ÐðŁłŠšÝýÞþŽž" ) );
    std::cout << ramp << "\n";
    std::cout << ramp[5] << "\n";
    u_printf( "%C\n", ramp[5] );
}
```

Compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 testme.cpp -licuio -licuuc`.

```
ÐðŁłŠšÝýÞþŽž
353
š
```

---

(1) ICU uses UTF-16 internally, and `UnicodeString::operator[]` returns a code *unit*, not a code *point*, so you might end up with one half of a surrogate pair. Look up the [API docs](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html) for the various other ways to index a unicode string.

Comment: Which distribution of ICU is best for Xcode in mac?

Comment: Errr... which *distribution*? I don't get your meaning. Since there's no binary package for the Mac, I'd think you take the latest source release and compile / install that?

Comment: There was binary distribution to install ICU on different platforms, but I guess I'll download the source. Thanks for such a detailed answer. It's a lot of information to digest.

Comment: Some Chinese and Emoji characters do not fit in a single UTF-16 character.

Comment: @RickJames: That is what the part about non-BMP characters and UTF-16 surrogate pairs was about, yes. And even if you're using UTF-32 encoding, there's combining characters.

Comment: @DevSolar - "Surrogate pairs" and "Combining characters" are two different issues.  The former is for encoding bigger-than-16 bit values using 2 16-bit values.  The latter is for having, say, a "combining acute accent" and a letter -- two different codepoints -- to represent an accented letter.  Some Chinese and Emoji need Surrogate pairs in UTF-16, but they are not combining characters.

Comment: @RickJames: Yes, I know that, and (with regards to surrogate pairs) said as much in my answer. You are commenting on this, so apparently you think this answer needs to be improved in some way. What would that be?

Comment: A definition of "code unit" would help.  And when a C++ programmer needs to care about such.  When I followed the ICU code, I got stopped by not finding the definition of `UChar` -- is it 16 bits or 32?  So, I could not determine whether that operator[], as you say, returns a code unit or point.  And what does return a `codepoint`?

Comment: (Otherwise, we are probably agreeing with each other.)

Comment: @RickJames: Code unit vs. Code point is right there in the footnote. No, this is not a complete primer to Unicode for C++. I meant to write one such for the FAQ, but never got around to actually doing so....

Answer (score 5):

C++ has no useful native Unicode support. You almost certainly will need an external library like ICU.

Answer (score 2):

To access codepoints individually, use `u32string`, which represents a string as a sequence of UTF-32 code units of type `char32_t`.

```
u32string ramp = U"ÐðŁłŠšÝýÞþŽž";
cout << ramp << "\n";    
cout << ramp[5] << "\n";
```

Comment: Yes; but you should have mentioned C++11

Comment: interestingly `cout << ramp << "\n"; ` will not compile with [G++ or Clang++ on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7e2fdf35b9f259f)

Comment: @NathanOliver Rightfully so, a `char32_t` is not a `char`, and that's what `std::cout` handles.

Comment: And since `wcout` handles `wchar_t`, which isn't `char32_t` either on Windows, we kind of see where standard C++ still doesn't handle Unicode all that well. Better than C++98, but you still need ICU if you want to go the whole way.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the best solution is to do any task with strings using iterators. I can't imagine a scenario where one **really has to** index strings: if you need indexing like `ramp[5]` in your example, then the `5` is usually computed in other part of the code and usually you scan all the preceding characters anyway. That's why Standard Library uses iterators in its API.

A similar problem comes up if you want to get the size of a string. Should it be character (or code point) count or merely number of bytes? Usually you need the size to allocate a buffer so byte count is more desirable. You only very, very rarely have to get Unicode character count.

If you want to process UTF-8 encoded strings using iterators then I would definitely recommend [UTF8-CPP](https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp).

Answer (score 0):

Answering about what is going on, [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) makes it clear:

> Note that this class handles bytes independently of the encoding used: If used to handle sequences of multi-byte or variable-length characters (such as UTF-8), all members of this class (such as length or size), as well as its iterators, will still operate in terms of bytes (not actual encoded characters).

About the solution, others had it right: [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) if you are not using C++11; [u32string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/u32string/) if you are.

Comment: Even `u32string` isn't a complete answer, unfortunately -- and space-ineffecient as well. I would suggest sticking with ICU even when C++11 is available.