# How to import non-ASCII characters into console?

Tags: c++, c++17

I've been scratching my head for a while at this and I am in need of some assistance. Basically what I want the code to do is read in a series of non-ASCII symbols into an empty pre-set array, and I'm printing them to see if they do get read in which they currently did not. Notepad displays them just fine but for some reason C++ doesn't recognise them as valid characters, any advice that is only about code and not changing the internal settings of my computer are strongly preferred.

```
char displayCharacters[5] = {};

try {

    instream.open("characters.txt");
    instream >> displayCharacters;
    cout << "Here is the first symbol: " << displayCharacters[4];

} 

catch (exception) {

    cout << "Something went wrong with the file handling.";

}
```

And yes I have set up the instreams correctly, with the cout having been used from the import of iostream and using namespace std. Here's what the file contains:

```
█
 
▀
▄
▓
```

Edit: The file is UTF-8 if you need to know.

Comment: If your file isn’t ASCII, what encoding does it use? (I’m assuming UTF-8 since those characters are rendering OK in my browser)

Comment: Well yes it is UTF-8, probably should have clarified. Let me edit.

Comment: What's in your input file? Can you post a program that compiles instead of a snippet?

Comment: Use some UTF-8 library, perhaps [GNU libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/), or [Qt](https://qt.io/), or [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/)

Comment: I've included the contents of the file inside of the question itself, and are there perhaps any libraries that come pre-installed I could use or do I need to find one of the ones you listed I like?

Answer (score 8):

### tl;dr;

You need to *decode* UTF-8 before you can index it. Read on for more details than I was expecting to write…

---

A C++ stream isn’t encoding-aware – it’s just a stream of bytes. For example, this code to dump an entire UTF-8 string works just fine:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    // Simulate your `instream` using an `std::stringstream`
    std::stringstream instream;
    // Load the simulated `instream` using a UTF-8 string literal [1]
    instream << u8"█\n \n▀\n▄\n▓\n";
    
    // Print entire `instream`
    std::cout << instream.rdbuf();
}
```

[1]: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Your problem comes from the UTF-8 encoding itself. UTF-8 is a **multibyte** encoding. Some characters (notably the ASCII characters) are encoded as a single byte. For instance, the letter `a` is encoded as the value 97 (`0x61` in hex).

Let’s take a look at the five characters you’re trying to print:

| Char | Unicode codepoint | UTF-8 encoding | Unicode name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `█` | `U+2588` | `0xe2` `0x96` `0x88` | [FULL BLOCK](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2588) |
|  | `U+20` | `0x20` | SPACE (*no link; this one’s just plain ASCII*) |
| `▀` | `U+2580` | `0xe2` `0x96` `0x80` | [UPPER HALF BLOCK](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2580) |
| `▄` | `U+2584` | `0xe2` `0x96` `0x84` | [LOWER HALF BLOCK](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2584) |
| `▓` | `U+2593` | `0xe2` `0x96` `0x93` | [DARK SHADE](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2593) |

The UTF-8 encoding is the interesting part here – that’s how each of these characters is stored as a sequence of bytes in a UTF-8 encoded file. For the four block-drawing characters (we’ll ignore the space because that’s just a single-byte character), the encoding takes three bytes.

*But why does the encoding take three bytes if the codepoint is only two bytes long?*

Good question. Let’s break down the first character:

```
   0xe2     0x96     0x88
 11100010 10010110 10001000
 AAAA^^^^ BB^^^^^^ BB^^^^^^
```

The annotations underneath the binary indicates how the encoding works.

Since the codepoint for the character is too big to fit into a single byte, UTF-8 breaks it into multiple bytes. However, there must be a way to determine that a sequence of bytes represents a single character, not just a sequence of simpler characters. This is where the byte prefixes (A, B and C) come into play. The first byte in the multibyte sequence begins with a sequence of `1` bits to represent the total number of bytes in the encoded character, followed by a terminating `0`. Here we need three bytes, so we have `1110` (A).

The prefixes of the remaining two bytes indicate that they are continuation bytes (i.e. they should not be considered the beginning of a character). The prefix for continuation bytes is defined as `10` (B).

After removing these prefixes, he remaining bits (marked with carets [`^`]) are packed and parsed to retrieve the encoded codepoint.

Single byte characters (i.e. the basic US-ASCII plane of characters from 0 to 127) only require 7 bits to encode, so a `0` bit is prefixed to indicate there are no continuation bytes for this character.

### What does all this have to do with your problem?

I said earlier that “*your problem comes from the UTF-8 encoding itself*”. Well, I lied. Sorry. Your problem comes from attempting to read UTF-8 encoded data as a plain sequence of bytes.

With the encoding table above, let’s take a look at the raw bytes in your file (assuming a single `\n` terminating each line):

```
e2 96 88 0a 20 0a e2 96 80 0a e2 96 84 0a e2 96 93 0a
\--01--/    02    \--03--/    \--04--/    \--05--/
```

I’ve marked the characters by their line numbers.

From this dump, you can easily see what the output of your problematic code will be:

```cpp
char displayCharacters[5] = {};
std::cout << "Here is the first symbol: " << displayCharacters[4];
```

It’s a space! Remember, the stream isn’t aware of the file’s encoding so it just spits out a sequence of bytes (a `char` in C/C++ is just an 8-bit variable). Your array (`displayCharacters`) contains the sequence of bytes shown above, so subscripting it to get the fourth (zero-indexed) element returns the byte `0x20`.

You actually got lucky here. Indexing UTF-8 data as raw bytes often causes much uglier errors. Remember those continuation bytes (beginning `10`)? If you extract and try to print one of those on its own, your terminal will have no idea what to do with it. Similarly with the beginning of a multibyte sequence (prefix `11`).

Properly indexing UTF-8 strings is [***hard***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31475700/1813169). You’ll almost certainly want a library to handle it.

Depending on the use and/or origin of the file in question, you might want to consider a fixed-width encoding such as [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32).

Comment: In that case might there be any libraries you recommend, and how would I change the encoding without changing the fundamental settings of my computer? All this information is rather teaching though, which I appreciate.

Comment: Basile’s suggestions in the comment under your question are all good. I’d throw [Boost.Locale](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html) into the mix, especially if you’re already using other Boost components in your project.

Comment: Well I have had a look at them, and while I assume they're all good my main issue with them is that they're all external libraries I'll need to download. I'm trying to do this with the base c++ package as I am somewhat afraid of handling more errors that may arise from the installation process of the libraries.

Comment: @Kitso You’re more likely to introduce errors by trying to do this yourself than by linking an established library that’s widely used.