# how to prevent wcscpy() function to stop copying data from spaces inbetween?

Tags: c++, unicode

I'm using a statement like

```
TCHAR path="";
wcscpy(path,_T("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Filename.ext"));
```

But its getting copied with spaces inbetween every character.How can i prevent it?

Comment: Could you provide some compilable example reproducing the problem?

Comment: Did you forget to escape your backslashes or is that just a typo?

Comment: Its a part of a huge project. Just need clarification on this part. Ask me questions on this for further clarity. I must strictly use only unicode character set. Just want to know is any other functions that can copy without spaces in between.

Comment: @ Mohamad Elghawi : Its just a typo

Comment: Where/how are you seeing spaces. Could it be that you are seeing a NULL character after each character?

Comment: TCHAR can be either char or wchar_t depending on your compiler settings. Since wscpy requires wchar_t pointers, your use of TCHAR is both redundant and dangerous. It is either wchar_t, in which case you could have just used wchar_t, or char, in which case the program is invalid.

Comment: @Mohamad Elghawi : Yeah i'm seeing NULL characters in between.

Comment: Sorry its not declared as TCHAR path=" ".But as TCHAR path[255];

Comment: @n.m.        I tried with wchar_t. But still its the same problem. There are spaces inbetween.

Comment: How do you display the result? Also, don't use `wcscpy` with `TCHAR` or `_T`, use `_tcscpy`.

Comment: Of course it has the same effect. It must either be the same, or fail altogether. That is, TCHAR introduces uncertainty to your code and nothing else. Which is what was trying to tell you. There are no spaces in between. You are misinterpreting your observations. Show an MCVE.

Comment: @ Sebastian Redl : I tried with _tcscpy too but still its the same result.

Comment: @ n.m          : I use visual studio 13. and while debugging i can see the memory as data is getting copied with null characters inbetween

Comment: @abejoe: Yes, there are NULL bytes in between, and that is perfectly normal in 16bit strings.  It will only cause problems if you are processing 16bit strings as 8bit data instead of 16bit data.

Answer (score 0):

You are **NOT** seeing spaces in between the characters.

`wchar_t` is **2 bytes** on Windows (**4 bytes** on other platforms). If you wish to use it to hold any ASCII character (ie: characters 0-127, which only require 1 byte), you will see that the first byte holds the character value and the additional bytes hold **NULL** bytes, since we only need 1 byte to hold the value (or 7 bits, to be more precise).  If you are looking at the string data as 8bit instead of 16bit/32bit, those NULLs will appear as spaces.

If you do not want this, use the `char` type instead.

On Windows, it is recommended to use `wchar_t` and `std::wstring` instead of `char` and `std::string`, especially when using the Win32 API since it will convert multi-byte strings to wide strings anyway.

Comment: Check out this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring) for a much more detailed explanation.