# How to parse Unicode symbols in C++? (like \u204c )

Tags: c++, unicode

I wonder, but my app stops before printing "\u064B"

```
std::wcout << L"{\"data\":\"string\",\"text\":\"\u00b2\u00b2\u064B BOB \u00b2\u00b2\u00b2}" << std::endl;
```

if I print:

```
std::wcout << L"{\"data\":\"string\",\"text\":\"\u00b2\u00b2\u00b2 BOB \u00b2\u00b2\u00b2}" << std::endl;
```

all is okay, why?

Comment: Its unclear what your asking, perhaps show a literal example of the string in question and describe what you want to do with it.

Comment: Have you looked at std::wstring? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring

Comment: ok i look into it, my question in general more about special characters witch appears then i work with some language.

Comment: I use MSVS C++ 2013, and i have problems then try promt in console lang-specific characters: "\u064B"
This characrter is just dont show in console, i dont know why, andalgorithms witch i use such as jsonparser just crush my app then try to deal with characters like "\u064B"

Comment: Your program is possibly fine, but console support of Unicode in Windows is very limited.  Search for questions about that topic to learn more.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=windows+console+unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  have  to use  "\\" when  you  want  to  print  '\'

```
std::wcout << L"{\"data\":\"string\",\"text\":\"\\u00b2\\u00b2\\u064B BOB \\u00b2\\u00b2\\u00b2}" << std::endl;
```