# C++ Terminal applications in spanish

Tags: c++, c++11

This code:

```
void ascii_es() {
    std::vector<int> list;
    std::wstring a;

    list.push_back( 160 );
    list.push_back( 181 );
    list.push_back( 130 );
    list.push_back( 144 );
    list.push_back( 161 );
    list.push_back( 214 );
    list.push_back( 162 );
    list.push_back( 224 );
    list.push_back( 168 );
    list.push_back( 164 );
    list.push_back( 165 );
    list.push_back( 163 );
    list.push_back( 233 );
    for(auto i : list) {
        a = i;
        wcout << L"Alt + " << i << L": " << a << std::endl;
    }
}
```

nicely displays all Spanish letters on my Win10 console, but this code

```
void DisplayEs() {
    std::locale myLoc;

    std::locale es("ES");
    std::locale::global(es);
    std::wcout.imbue(es);

    std::wcout << L"Has escogido Espa" << static_cast<char>(164) << "ol" << std::endl;

    std::locale::global(myLoc);
    std::wcout.imbue(myLoc);
}
```

does not display the letter ñ (Alt+164) at all.

My question is, why my VC++-12 program works perfectly in the first example, but in the second does not?

The examples are two functions in the same program, but they display differently on the Terminal?

Can anybody help?

Comment: making a [long story](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) short. It's the encoding. Change the terminal encoding to `utf-8` and then from your program output `utf-8` encoded strings via `cout` (not `wcout`).

Comment: Should `static_cast<char>(164)` be `static_cast<wchar>(164)`

Comment: And ` "ol"` be `L "ol"`

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283).

Comment: char can be signed or unsigned. If signed, `static_cast<char>(164)` creates an overflow and the result is actually -92.