# boost::filesystem::path vs boost::filesystem::wpath

Tags: c++, boost, encoding, path

Boost lib has a class to deal with file path: `boost::filesystem::path`.
Also Boos has this class `boost::filesystem::wpath`

Each class has methods `string()`, `wstring()`, `c_str()`, `native()`

I develop Windows app and I completely do not understand what should I use ))

What is the difference between these two classes from the practical point of view? What is the difference between these methods?

What class and what methods should I use for Windows app? `::wpath` and `wstring()` everywhere?

Part of sources (several statically linked libs) will be compiled for Ubuntu. In this situation `::wpath` still good?

---

Also I use `SQLite` and it needs path to the database file. [sqlite3_open](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html).

I should use `sqlite3_open_v2` (UTF-8 encoding for the file path) or `sqlite3_open16` (UTF-16 encoding for the file path) ?

---

P.S. After reading this article [link](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.filesystem-paths) seems that `::path` and `::wpath` have no difference at all. Is it right?

Method `native()` seems preferable for the source code that compiled for different platforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the difference between these two classes from the practical point of view? What is the difference between these methods?
>
> What class and what methods should I use for Windows app? ::wpath and wstring() everywhere?

Worth mentioning that for several releases now, Boost has deprecated `wpath` and `class path` should be used instead. See [Boost Deprecated Features (current release)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/deprecated.html)

"Under the hood", Boost represents `path` and `wpath` using `std::string` and `std::wstring` where `wstring` is used to represent wide character strings, i.e. supports larger character sets.

These questions for the most part are answered here: [std::wstring VS std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring)

> Method native() seems preferable for the source code that compiled for different platforms

That is correct. If it's solely a Windows app you are developing, then `wstring()` can  be used over `native()`