# Error C2664: 'Strategy::Interphase' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char *' to 'char *[]'

Tags: c++

I have never quite been able to wrap my head around pointers, strings, chars etc.
I need help with this error.
Here is the code snippet...

```
string H = "פטיש";
string G = "Σφυρί";

bool Interphase(int argc, char * args[]); //DLL import from Analytical.a

char * Hcopy = new char[H.length() + 1]; 
std::strcpy(Hcopy, H.c_str());
char * Gcopy = new char[G.length() + 1]; 
std::strcpy(Gcopy, G.c_str());

while (Interphase(147, Hcopy) == true || Interphase(148, Gcopy) == true)//C2664 here!
    {// Do stuff...}
```

Please note the code is altered to reflect the error only.

Also how to compile in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate without

```
Warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u05E9' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Warnings are helpful! Don't ignore them! The warning you are trying to remove is a helpful warning: `"פטיש"` can't be represented as a `char` array. This will most likely give you wrong results.

Comment: Why are you using pointers and C-strings at all? This is 2016, not 1972! Why not simply call `Interphase(147, &H[0])` and `Interphase(148, &G[0])`? (Are you sure those `argc` arguments are correct?)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Wikipedia C++: "First appeared  1983" OK.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: If you use the standardisation as starting point, to be fair, C started in 1990 (1989 in the US). However, they are still the way to go **in C** - which (I assume) is your actual point :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error:

> Error C2664: 'Strategy::Interphase' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char *' to 'char *[]'

means that you're giving a `char*` to the function which expects a `char*[]`.

```
bool Interphase(int argc, char * args[]);
```

Note the 2nd argument, it's a pointer to an array (or array of arrays, or pointer to pointer).

Your code can be modified to give it the address of the pointer:

```
while (Interphase(1, &Hcopy) == true || Interphase(1, &Gcopy) == true)
    // ...
```

but I doubt that's how the API is meant to be used.

I'm not familiar with that function, but I'm guessing it's used more like:

```
const char** args = {"arg1", "arg2"};
Interphase(2, args);
```

---

Your warning:

> Warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u05E9' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)

means that `char` can't hold non-ASCII characters.

If you're doing Unicode, you must use wide characters and strings ([`wchar_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wchar_t/) and [`wstring`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/)) to allow bigger numbers. Otherwise, you'll have an [overflow](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) and likely a wrap.

Link to [comparison between `string` and `wstring`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring).

---

As a side note, you really shouldn't use C-style strings (`char*`).
Use `std::string` instead.
The reason:

- Need to deallocate them yourself (your code leaks memory as-is)
- Unsafe api (needing to pass the size along with the data)

Comment: Actually `std::string`s store Unicode code points encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: @Bob__: Total nonsense. `std::string` stores bytes, and has no inherent encoding whatsoever.

Comment: @Ivan So my question would be how to pass strings into the Interphase(); function in the dll. Also changing from string to wstring only changes the error to Error C2664: 'Strategy::Interphase' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'wchar_t *' to 'char *[]'

Comment: @loumbut5 If the function takes a `char` then you can't expect it to work with non-ASCII strings like "פטיש". My answer shows an example of how to use the function.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, the real nonsense IMHO is that `std::string` is unaware of its encoding, but yes, it stores bytes. In some environments the byte sequence is natively encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: @Bob__: On the contrary, it's a good thing because you can use whatever encoding you like on top.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That's fine, but you should be able to know how it is encoded. In a simple way.

Comment: @Bob__: Yes, your project documentation states that information, as well as surrounding code comments around the string's declaration. Right?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yeah (not really, I'm afraid), but the Standard Library is unaware of the encoding too. To sort a string like `"Olé"` with `std::sort`, for example, I have to convert it to UTF-32 or UTF-16 before. I find it an inconvenience (IMHO, again).

Comment: @Bob__: It's not an inconvenience. It is a convenience. If everybody in the entire world were forced to use an encoding just because Bob__ wanted to use it. Can you imagine! Instead you are free to encode your string over your bytes however you like, using the appropriate library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122687/discussion-between-bob-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Comment: Nah that's okay

Comment: Ok, one error down. Thanks @Ivan. Now how to solve Error C2196: case value '?' already used. The code goes like case 'א': if (/*Conditional*/) {/*Do stuff*/}