# C++ String to lowercase with custom locale

Tags: c++, locale, tolower

I've been trying to call `std::tolower()` with a different locale but it seems that something is going wrong. My code is as follows:

```
int main() {
    std::locale::global(std::locale("es_ES.UTF-8"));
    std::thread(&function, this); // Repeated some times
    // wait for threads
}

void function() {
    std::string word = "HeÉllO";
    std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), cToLower);
}

int cToLower(int c) {
    return std::tolower(c, std::locale());
}
```

So when I try to execute this program I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
terminate called recursively
  what():  std::bad_cast
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Although executing `return std::tolower(c);` works fine, but it just converts the 'standard' characters to lower, and not `É`.

I have some threads which are executing the same function simultaneously, using C++11 and compiling with g++ (in case it has something to do with it).

I was wondering if this is the correct way to implement what I want to do, or there's some other way of doing it.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to find out if the problem is with threading or with the locale. 1.) Does it work in a single-threaded program? 2.) Does it work with an English string and the default locale in a multi-threaded program?

Comment: Try `std::tolower((unsigned char)c, std::locale())`. From [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower): "If the value of `ch` is not representable as unsigned char and does not equal `EOF`, the behavior is undefined." The problem is, `char` is usually signed, and characters like `É` are represented as negative values, which then fall outside the range of `unsigned char`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, Correct!. please make that an answer. :-)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik still a bad_cast is thrown. I understand the logic you present but looks like I will have to use wstring instead.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That applies only to the single-parameter version from the C standard library, not the two-parameter one from C++ `<locale>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if locale you are trying to use installed on your system. For example I have to install Spanish locale before code below stop crashing.
Additionally you could work with `wstring` instead.
**Update**: after some digging [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring) is good explanation of using `wstring` - all cons and procs (cons mostly).

```
#include <thread>
#include <locale>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <iostream>

//forward declaration
void function();

int main() {
    std::locale::global(std::locale("es_ES.utf8"));
    std::thread test(&function);
    test.join();
}

wchar_t cToLower(wchar_t c) {        
    return std::tolower(c, std::locale());    
}

void function() {
    std::wstring word = L"HeÉllO";
    std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), cToLower);
    std::wcout << word;
}
```

Output:

```
heéllo
```

Comment: It does work using `wstring` but I really need to use `string`. Isn't there any other alternative?

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work -crash or lower case hasn't  been applied?

Comment: It DOES work :) But I need a workaround to use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike the version of `tolower` that came from C (which takes characters converted to `unsigned` char and then to `int`), the `<locale>` version of `tolower` is meant to be called with characters directly. It is defined to use the `std::ctype<charT>` facet of the locale, and the only two `std::ctype` specializations [guaranteed to be available](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/localization#tab:localization.category.facets) are `std::ctype<char>` and `std::ctype<wchar_t>`. Thus:

```
char cToLower(char c) {
    return std::tolower(c, std::locale());
}
```

Note that this is still a `char`-by-`char` transform; if the character occupies more than one byte, it is unlikely to handle it properly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I see what you mean, but although this compiles, it doesn't transform the special characters like `É` to `é`.

Comment: @lpares12 Well, I can't test it, but is `É` actually a single `char`? If it actually takes more than one byte, then a byte-by-byte transformation (which is what you are doing) won't cut it.

Comment: `É` and `é` are represented in decimal as `144` and `130` respectively, so both should fit inside a byte. But now that I think of it, it should be represented as `unsigned char`, otherwise they both would have negative values.

Comment: @lpares12 Well, [U+00C9](https://codepoints.net/U+00C9) ("LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH ACUTE") is encoded as two bytes in UTF-8, likewise for U+00E9 ("LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE"). I'm not sure what encoding you are using.