# printing UTF-8 yields different output

Tags: c++, windows, macos

The objective is to print `Uni Würzburg` using C++

The code I am using:

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char str0[21] = "Uni Würzburg";
    printf("%s\n", str0);
    char str1[21] = {85,110,105,32,87,'\xc3','\xbc',114,122,98,117,114,103, 0};
    printf("%s\n", str1);
    char str2[20] = "Uni W\x81rzburg";
    printf("%s\n", str2);
    char str3[20] = {85,110,105,32,87,'\x81',114,122,98,117,114,103, 0};
    printf("%s\n", str3);
    return 0;
}
```

I got the `\xc3bc` from creating a `"ü"` string and printing the characters.

Output on two different Macs (using both CLion and in bash using `g++ test.c -o test`):

```
Uni Würzburg
Uni Würzburg
Uni W�rzburg
Uni W�rzburg
```

Output on Windows (CLion):

```
Uni W├╝rzburg
Uni W├╝rzburg
Uni Würzburg
Uni Würzburg
```

CLion editor and project encodings are in all cases set to UTF-8 and the locale of bash is:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Why is this happening? Most importantly: What would be a platform independent solution?

Comment: Here is the answer you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/402918/5470596

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There unicode literals that can be used to ensure that your string is encoded as UTF-8:

`u8"my_string"`

On Linux these your normal strings will be already UTF-8.

On Windows it is really depending on your codpeage.
And you may also supply additional compiler flag: `/source-charset:utf-8`

Note that even if your strings are encoded as UTF-8, cout, on Windows, that prints to console with non-unicode codepage will get you wrong output.