# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream'; Also getting error -> No such file or directory and 'stdlib.h'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

**I keep getting these issues when trying to compile this certain project :**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: X, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>ESPWork.cpp
1>D:\X\test\ESPWork.cpp(1,9): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory
1>Source.cpp
1>D:\X\test\Source.cpp(1,9): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory
1>MemoryManager.cpp
1>D:\X\test\MemoryManager.cpp(1,9): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory
1>DirectXM.cpp
1>D:\MicrosoftDirectXSDK\Include\d3d9.h(37,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdlib.h': No such file or directory
1>Generating Code...
1>Done building project "test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**I have include directories set to (D:\MicrosoftDirectXSDK\Include)
and library directories set to (D:\MicrosoftDirectXSDK\Lib\x86)**

New issue:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SAFU_IRAQ, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>DirectXM.cpp
1>D:\Eary\test\MemoryManager.h(7,32): error C2039: 'wstring': is not a member of 'std'
1>D:\Stufff\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\list(24): message : see declaration of 'std'
1>D:\Eary\test\MemoryManager.h(7,39): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\Eary\test\MemoryManager.h(7,39): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
1>Done building project "test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Which Visual studio version you are using?

Comment: I'm using VS 2019

Comment: I think then Include directories should having value => $(VC_IncludePath); $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);

Comment: how to use that? can you like give an example on (D:\MicrosoftDirectXSDK\Include)

Comment: Actually those are default values expected to be set to include system ISO standard files. Like => C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28\include

Comment: Oh what should I do then

Comment: I have included the path version number might be different. Check similar kind of path on your system.

Comment: I have just solved the issue by trying something else different than what you mentioned, but I'm running into new issues now:

Comment: I have added the new issue to the main post, because its too long to write in a comment under ''New issue:''

Comment: Now, you have to show some code as per the errors these are due to your wrong code. Those are not configuration errors.

Comment: Here's the code that I'm having issues with : 
https://throwbin.io/35q1UW4

Comment: Any idea so far?

Comment: wstring is not recognized. It may be wchar_t or need an include? See also the discussion on its use on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring