# Why I can't construct a wstring from char*

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, type-conversion, wstring

According I build fill a `char*` from this code :

```
char* pathAppData = nullptr;
size_t sz = 0;
_dupenv_s(&pathAppData, &sz, "APPDATA");
```

I can easily construct a `string` with this code and `append` this `string` in the future :

```
std::string sPathAppData(pathAppData);
sPathAppData.append("\\MyApplication");
```

But I can't create a `wstring` from this code. Why is so complicated to work with `wstring` ? I am going crazy with all theses types.

```
std::wstring wPathAppData(pathAppData); // Impossible
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `wchar_t` directly and use corresponding `wchar_t` supported API to retrieve data directly to `wchar_t` and then construct `wstring`. `_dupenv_s` function has a wide counterpart - [_wdupenv_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/dupenv-s-wdupenv-s?view=vs-2019).

Your code then would look like this:

```
wchar_t* pathAppData = nullptr;
size_t sz = 0;
_wdupenv_s(&pathAppData, &sz, L"APPDATA");
std::wstring wPathAppData(pathAppData);
wPathAppData.append(L"\\MyApplication")
```

Also this could be an interesting read: [std::wstring VS std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use iterator to make copy. This is how you can do it.

```
char* pathAppData = nullptr;
size_t sz = 0;
_dupenv_s(&pathAppData, &sz, "APPDATA");
std::string sPathAppData(pathAppData);
sPathAppData.append("\\MyApplication");

std::wstring wPathAppData(begin(sPathAppData), end(sPathAppData));
wcout << wPathAppData << endl;
```

Comment: `std::wstring wPathAppData(pathAppData, pathAppData + strlen(pathAppData));` would also work, and avoids creating a temporary `std::string`. It works because pointers are iterators too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works but I validate the @Robertas answer because it more direct.