# How to get output in other spoken languages other than English?

Tags: c++, calculator

I want to make an calculator in a spoken language another than English e.g. Hindi. I tried to make one using '''cout''' function but it gave me unexpected errors. Please Tell what should I do

**Code Sample**

```
cout<<name<<", "<<"कृपया ऑपरेटर दर्ज करें--> ";
cin>>op;
switch (op)
{
    case '+':
     cout<<name<<", "<<"कृपया पहला नंबर दर्ज करें--> ";
     cin>>x;
     cout<<name<<", "<<"कृपया दूसरा नंबर दर्ज करें--> ";
     cin>>y;
```

**Result:**

```
    αñòαÑâαñ¬αñ»αñ╛ αñæαñ¬αñ░αÑçαñƒαñ░ αñªαñ░αÑìαñ£ αñòαñ░αÑçαñé--> +
αñòαÑâαñ¬αñ»αñ╛ αñ¬αñ╣αñ▓αñ╛ αñ¿αñéαñ¼αñ░ αñªαñ░αÑìαñ£ αñòαñ░αÑçαñé-->
αñòαÑâαñ¬αñ»αñ╛ αñªαÑéαñ╕αñ░αñ╛ αñ¿αñéαñ¼αñ░ αñªαñ░αÑìαñ£ αñòαñ░αÑçαñé-->
```

Comment: You need a terminal (and an appropriate font) that supports the encoding of your strings.

Comment: @molbdnilo Can you suggest any terminal and font. I am new to C++ so I don't know more about this things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Display output in Hindi or any none language, we Firstly need to set UTF encoding to output encoding

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    std::string test = u8"Greek: αβγδ; German: Übergrößenträger";
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
    std::cout << test;
}
```

Comment: What if the OP is not using Windows, or is but wants to write portable code?

Comment: @Vaibhav I am able to display the letters when I copy them and paste them in my browser but when I run my application in Command Prompt it shows question marks instead of letters

Comment: maybe you can display a message  by converting it message into utf-8

Comment: @VaibhavMahajan Have look at [link](https://ibb.co/4p8SkDz) It is same as before after encoding UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Hindi font used in console, but you need to do the following things:-

- Set the correct code page using [std::locale](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) OR use unicode (for examplestd::wstring and std::wcout).
- Set your console to a font that can display those characters.

I would suggest you to find the character set Hindi, like English has `ASCII` (classification `ISO646` series).

You can find more info about `wstring` and `wcout` , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring/402918#402918) posted by a fellow user.Remember to save the code file to UTF8 (or in the correct locale) otherwise the characters will simply 'disappear' from the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *setlocale* function in C++. You can include *locale.h* header (if you need more C specific functionality, this functionality can give possibility to play with currency, language and so on).
Example code:

```
include <locale.h>

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"en_US.utf8");
    
    // Your code
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Explanation**: *setlocale* function sets locale information to be used by the current program instead of changing whole locale. *setlocale* function accepts two parameters: 1. category (`LC_ALL`); 2. locale (`"en_US.utf8"`). Locales can be different.
Reference: [setlocale in c++ (reference)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/setlocale/)
This function helped me a lot in my projects.